# Calculating the ensemble average of a known function multiplied with a random term in a Langevin equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Let's say I have a Langevin equation that reads
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = A(t) + B(t) + \eta(t)$$

Where $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are some non-random functions that we know the functional form of, and $\eta(t)$ is a random term. For the sake of this question, lets say it has Gaussian properties such that it has zero mean, a finite standard deviation and $\langle\eta(t_1)\eta(t_2)\rangle = D\delta(t_1-t_2)$.

If $A(t) = B(t) = 0$, the equation just describes a random walk, and we can calculate

$$\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle = \int_{0}^{t_1}\int_{0}^{t_2}\langle\eta(t'_1)\eta(t'_2)\rangle dt'_1dt'_2$$
$$\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle = \int_{0}^{t_1}\int_{0}^{t_2}D\delta(t'_1-t'_2) dt'_1dt'_2$$
$$ \langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle= Dt_1$$

But now lets say we know that $A(t)\neq 0$ and $B(t)\neq 0$. If we now calculate $\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle$ we have

$$\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle = \int_{0}^{t_1}\int_{0}^{t_2}\Big\langle(A(t'_1) + B(t'_1) + \eta(t'_1))(A(t'_2) + B(t'_2) + \eta(t'_2))\Big\rangle dt'_1dt'_2$$

And we find we have ensemble average terms where we mix random and non-random terms for example
$$\langle A(t'_1)\eta(t'_2)\rangle$$

My question is: how do you deal with these terms? In the case of only random terms, only one term $\langle\eta(t_1)\eta(t_2)\rangle = D\delta(t_1-t_2)$ appears under the integral which we've defined before. But how do we deal with the ensemble average terms with both random and non-random terms in it?

Comment: Why differentiate between $A$ and $B$? You can reformulate the question in terms of $C(t)=A(t)+B(t)$ without loss of generality. The functions do not depend on an stochastic process (e.g. $A(\eta)$ or $A(x)$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-random function behaves as a constant in respect to statistical averaging, that is
$$
\langle A(t_1)\eta(t_2)\rangle=A(t_1)\langle \eta(t_2)\rangle=0
$$
(the second equality is because the OP assumes that the random process has the zero average.)

**Remarks**

- A word of caution - why are there explicitly two different non-random functions in the equation? It might be that one of them is a function of $x(t)$, in which case it is no more a non-random term, and the problem is more complex.
- As linear differential equations are exactly solvable, the corresponding Langevin equations can be formally solved and the solutions used for calculating all the necessary averages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added two non-random functions because I also was wondering about the case for $\langle A(t_1)B(t_2)\rangle$, though this case should be answered by your response, and it just comes out to be $\langle A(t_1)B(t_2)\rangle =A(t_1)B(t_2) $?

If there was another term, $C(x(t))$, how would this be dealt with in calculating $\langle C(x(t_1))\eta(t_2)\rangle$ and also $\langle C(x(t_1))A(t_2)\rangle$?

Comment: @physics_fan_123 if there were a term dependent on $x(t)$, the problem would be a lot more complex, since $x(t)$ depends on $\eta (t)$. However, if the equation is linear, it would be still tractable - see my remarks. Otherwise, one would have to use more special techniques... Or work with the Fokker Planck equation.

Answer (score 2):

Given a deterministic function, $f(t)$, then it follows from [Ito isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry) & independent increments that
$$ \int_0^tf(u)\,\mathrm{d}W_u\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\,\int_0^tf^2(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right).\tag{1}$$
where $W_t$ is the [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) (such that one could at least loosely say $\mathrm{d}W_t=\eta(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$) and $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma)$ is the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). This is to say, the integral in Eq (1) is a Gaussian process with zero mean--see, for instance, [these lecture notes](http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/bdauria/0910/Stoc_Proc_PhD/Notes/2010-04-13Tu_Notes.pdf). So one can safely ignore these terms when we average them out,
$$\left\langle\int f(u)\,\mathrm{d}W_u\right\rangle\equiv0.$$
In the cases we don't take an average, we could replace the integral with an arbitrary term, e.g.
$$Z(t)\sim\int f(u)\,\mathrm{d}W,$$
and not really miss anything when solving stochastic differential equation (though a final solution might need to be solved numerically or through an approximation such as being small compared to another term).